# Taking data JSON format files in R

Tags: r, grepl

I have imported a JSON file in R with the following format:

```
$ Singapore                                   : chr [1:34] "Singapore" "Yishun New Town" "Bedok New Town" "Ayer Raja New Town" ...
$ Indonesia                                   : chr [1:273] "Bandung" "Jakarta" "Samarinda" "Pekanbaru" ...
$ Nepal                                       : chr [1:6] "Patan" "Jawlakhel" "Kathmandu" "Bharatpur" ...
```

And I have another data.frame which has text variable:

```
1                                   "yishun"
2                                    "patan"
3                           "samarinda city"
4                         "kathmandu center"
5                           "Bedok new town"
```

So what I want is to go through the JSON file check if this city exist and assign the country to a new variable, like the following:

```
1                                   "yishun"    Singapure
2                                    "patan"        Nepal
3                           "samarinda city"      donesia 
4                         "kathmandu center"        Nepal
5                                 "New york"           NA
```

I was thinking to use: `unlist()` the JSON file -> use `grepl` to find if there is a city in the value. Any other idea?

Comment: Seems that `JSON` has no role in this matter, aside the fact that your data were _once_ in a JSON format. Am I wrong? If not, please edit the title of your question, which may be misleading. On the other hand, I think your approach is good.

Comment: I think it has no role. Do you recommend to change it in specific format?

Comment: What I meant is that your object looks very much like a standard R `list`. It doesn't have anything to do with JSON. For your task the fact that (I guess) you extracted your data from a JSON file is  irrelevant.